# Check specific integer is even

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to know if the 4th integer in the ID, is even, or if its odd.

If the 4th number is even (if the number is either 0,2,4,6,8 I want to put the ID into a new column named 'even'

IF the 4th number is odd, the column should have the name 'Odd'

```
select ID as 'Female'
from Users2
where ID LIKE '%[02468]'
```

This shows if any of the numbers are even. I want to specify the 4th number

Comment: I couldn't make any sense out of this. Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: edited a bit thanks

Comment: You want to check whether the ID value in 4th row is odd or even?

Comment: If I have a ID like 4545-4400, I want to know if 454(5)-4400  is odd. As 5 is odd, I will put this ID in a column named 'Odd'. If it was even, column would be named 'even'

Comment: my question is how to specify to check one specific number, of them all?

Comment: I have a list of plenty of ID's. all of the IDs where the 4th number is even, will go into one new column. All of the ID  where the 4th number is a odd number, will go to another

Comment: Now I get it :)

Comment: If it is an `int` column could you not just do modulo `WHERE ID % 2 = 0`?

Comment: This checks if the sum of the numbers are odd? I needed to know if a specific number is odd or even

Comment: @EST203 the term you are looking for is "digit" - number refers to the entire thing, digit refers to 1 character of a number.

Comment: yes you are totally right, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select *, OddOrEven = iif(substring(ID,4,1) in ('0','2','4','6','8') , 'Even', 'Odd') from Users2
```

This will tell you whether the 4th character is Odd or Even.
This is of course assuming that the 4th character of ID column will be numeric.

To make it permanently part of the table, you can add a computed column as shown below.

```
alter table Users2
add OddOrEven as iif(substring(ID,4,1) in ('0','2','4','6','8'), 'Even', 'Odd')
```

Comment: Yep. Perfect! Cheers

Comment: I think this one does not add the column, I want to add it into a new column with name eg. NewUsers

Comment: @EST203, do you need a permanent column in the table?

Answer (score 1):

- Substring the character you are interested in
- Convert to an `int`
- Check whether modulus 2 returns 0 (i.e. even).

```sql
select id
  , case when convert(int,substring(id, 4, 1)) % 2 = 0 then 'Even' else 'Odd' end
from Users;
```

Example:

```sql
select id
  , case when convert(int,substring(id, 4, 1)) % 2 = 0 then 'Even' else 'Odd' end
from (values ('4545-4400'), ('4546-4400')) X (id);
```

Returns

| id |  |
| --- | --- |
| 4545-4400 | Odd |
| 4546-4400 | Even |

Thats assuming there is always a 4th character. If not you would need to check for it.

Comment: Why `2.0` and not `2`, and can we not assume that actually *is* an `int` column?

Comment: Missed that. Dunno, I often saw stuff not formatted properly and putting 4 backticks seemed to sort it out. [Looks like you're right only needs 3](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) I do usually add the language as that gets it colour-coded

Answer (score 0):

You were close, but only need to check a single character against a set of characters:

```
where Substring( Id, 4, 1 ) like '[02468]'
```

Note that there is no wildcard (`%`) in the pattern.

It can be used in an expression like:

```
case when Substring( Id, 4, 1 ) like '[02468]' then 'Even' else 'Odd' end as Oddity
```